# Keep getting access violation errors in Delphi FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

im trying to make a gradient paintbrush to be drawn onto a sphere but when i click on the button i keep getting access violation error i dont know why i keep getting this error

```
var
 DLine     : TLine;
begin
//gradient paintbrush With transition animation and screenshot output
  DLine.Stroke.Thickness := 3;
  DLine.Stroke.Gradient.Color :=  $ff0000;  //Red
  DLine.Stroke.Gradient.Color1 := $0000ff;  //Blue
  DLine.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Gradient;
  DLine.Stroke.Gradient.Style := TGradientStyle.Linear;

end
```

Comment: In addition to not creating the TLine object, you have also set the colours incorrectly. They will both appear as fully transparent because you've not specified the alpha part. You should set $FFFF0000 for red, or better still use TAlphaColorRec.Red.

Comment: @XylemFlow i know that this is unrelated  to  my question but how would i add a color animation from red to blue kind of like a paint over effect

Comment: I don't know if there's an easy solution, but I would interpolate the red, green and blue parts in a TTimer event. At each interval you can use MakeColor to create a TAlphaColor from the r,g,b values and apply them to your Line stroke.

Comment: @XylemFlow i added DLine := TLine.Create(Form); but it still shows access violation errors  when i click on the tracerad button

Comment: You should post a full working example, not just a small section of code. Then we can help more. You should probably add DLine as a member of the form class, because currently its scope is only in that function. I don't know what tracerad is.

Answer (score 2):

TLine is an OBJECT/CLASS that you need to create before you use it, like

```
DLine := TLine.Create(Form);
```

where Form is the form which the graphic you're drawing on is owned by.

But it may be that you don't need to create one yourself. It may be that the object you're trying to draw the line on already have one allocated that is destined to work on that object.

On what are you trying to draw a line (which object/class)?

Comment: im trying to draw a line onto a sphere in viewport 3d

Comment: @CHRssggg I don't understand your comment above. You asked about the "Access violation error" and HeartWare answered that question. Do you know that you can mark a correct answer by clicking the tick mark beside the answer, green. Please do so.